# Run Unix command cat in windows to combine splitted zip files

Tags: perl

I want to combine splitted zip files in windows. In linux system, I can do it by

```
$prefixfiles = "splittedfiles*"
$outputfile = "combined.zip"
@output = `cat $prefixfiles > $outputfile`
```

However, in windows when I want to replicate the same (with Exutils), I got an corrupted zip file saying "Unexpected end of archive"

```
use ExtUtils::Command;
$prefixfiles = "splittedfiles*"
$outputfile = "combined.zip"
@output = `perl -MExtUtils::Command -e cat $prefixfiles > $outputfile`
```

I tried using binmode before

```
binmode "C:\linktofile\splittedfilesaa";
```

Anybody can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler answer.  Replace `cat` with `type` and redirect stderr to nul: (equivalent to /dev/null)

```
@output = `type $prefixfiles > $outputfile 2>nul:`
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows console shell, You can use the `copy` command to concatenate files with the `+` operator.  Example to combine file1.txt, file2.txt, and file3.txt into a "final.txt" file:

```
copy /b /y file1.txt+file2.txt+file3.txt final.txt
```

The `/b` option is to indicate to Windows/DOS that the files should be treated as binary ("as-is") and not to insert or re-interpret end-of-line chars during the copy operation.

`/y` indicates "don't prompt for overwrite confirmation"

Fix up your perl script along with the @output and $prefixfiles variable as appropirate to do the same thing.